# ManyToManyField how I can store many data in one DB field -- Django

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Roles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Permission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    create = models.BooleanField(max_length=5)
    read = models.BooleanField(max_length=5)
    update = models.BooleanField(max_length=5)
    delete = models.BooleanField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RolesHasPermission(models.Model):
    role_id = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    permission_id = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
```

In `RoleHasPermission` I need to store many `permission_id` names in one `role_id` field in DB
How can I do this? I have tried a lot but I can't find the solution for this problem.

for example :-

i want to make the role_id take many permission names example if i have in my permissions ,, Manager (Read, Update , Delete) IT (Create) and have in my Role ,, Admin i want to make the Admin Role take two permissions (Manager , IT) together by make model make me select from list my role Admin and checkbox for Manager and checkbox for IT when i chose Admin Role and Check the Box of Manager and IT and press Save it will store it in DB (Admin || Manager,IT)

Answer (score 0):

[Django comes with simple permissions by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization), which I strongly recommend to use.

Apart from that, I'm not sure what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want to make the role_id take many permission names example if i have in my permissions ,, Manager (Read, Update , Delete) IT (Create) and have in my Role ,, Admin i want to make the Admin Role take two permissions (Manager , IT) together by make model make me select from list my role Admin and checkbox for Manager and checkbox for IT when i chose Admin Role and Check the Box of Manager and IT and press Save it will store it in DB (Admin || Manager,IT)

Comment: Why won't you use builtin permissions for such a case? Why do you need to create your own?